name field is not working in angular html file - appearing as object Object
I want to validate the name entered in the form.
<tr><td><label>Name</label></td>
       <td><input required #fullname="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="name"[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"></td>
       <div *ngIf="fullname.errors && fullname.errors?.['$invalid']" class="naming naming-info">Name is Invalid</div>
    </tr> 

[object Object] is appearing when i run the application, also Validity is not working.
I tried changing name, or removing [ngModelOptions]={"standalone: true} then, it is not binding.
Please help

[(ngModel)]="name"[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" there's a space missing between "name" and [ngModelOptions]

It's because your variable name is not a string (perhafs you have a template ref variable with the same "name"). BTW if your input is not inside a formGroup, remove the [ngModelOptions]

Check
First, make sure your component has the correct imports and declarations to use ngModel. Ensure that you have imported FormsModule in your module file.
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    // other imports
  ],
  // other declarations
})
export class YourModule { }

Update you template:
<tr>
  <td><label for="name">Name</label></td>
  <td>
    <input 
      required 
      id="name" 
      name="name" 
      #fullname="ngModel" 
      [(ngModel)]="name" 
      type="text" 
      class="form-control" 
      placeholder="Enter Name">
  </td>
  <td>
    <div *ngIf="fullname.invalid && (fullname.dirty || fullname.touched)" class="naming naming-info">
      Name is Invalid
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>

Example Component Class
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
})
export class YourComponent {
  name: string = '';
}

